# ASP.NET Core WebApplicationFactory CreateClient Booting Server Blocking on GitLab CI When Run In Docker Compose Environment

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab-ci, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a functional tests project for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 API that uses WebApplicationFactory to create a test server for the API. The tests pass locally and within a local docker-compose environment.

However when run on the GitLab CI server within the same docker-compose environment the WebApplication factory's `CreateClient` method is blocking. When the test server starts the confluent Kafka Admin Service is blocking, i.e no confirmation log message is displayed confirming the topic created. I have created a small [project](https://gitlab.com/faultfinding/kafkaadminclient) on GitLab to highlight the issue.

The issue appears to be with the WebApplication test server and Confluent Kafka somehow, since I have created a docker-compose stack that starts the Software Under Test WebApp on GitLab CI and it starts successfully.

The Software Under Test contains Background / Hosted Services:

- Kafka Admin Service to create topic - this is blocking on CI server when using WebAppicationFactory test server
- Kafka Consumer
- MqttKafkaBridge

It also uses Autofac and starts a SignalR Hub.

Has anyone experienced similar issue/problems when using `WebApplicationFactory` on a remote CI server such as Gitlab or Travis?

Is it because `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()` creates a `TestServer` that runs as localhost??

**Test using WebApplicationFactory**

Create a WebApplicationFactory for the Sofware Under Test and display console log message once  created. When run on CI Server no console message is displayed for after the factory client has been created.

```
  [Fact]
        public void WebApp_ApiController_DownloadImage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST WebApp_ApiController_DownloadImage");

            var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<WebApp.Startup>()
               .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                  {
                  });

            /** THIS CODE HANGS WHILE Bootsrapping the Services in Startup **/
            /** NO TEST MESSAGE IS DISPLAYED **/
            using (var client = appFactory.CreateClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WE ARE IN THE TEST HERE");
            }
        }
```

**Startup.cs**

Contains background services for Kafka and Mqtt

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services
                .AddCustomConfiguration(Configuration)
                .AddBackgroundServices()
                .AddLogging()
                .AddCustomSignalR();
        }


        // ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly
        // with Autofac. This runs after ConfigureServices so the things
        // here will override registrations made in ConfigureServices.
        // Don't build the container; that gets done for you by the factory.
        public virtual void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register your own things directly with Autofac here. Don't
            // call builder.Populate(), that happens in AutofacServiceProviderFactory
            // for you.
            builder.RegisterModule(new MqttModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new MotionDetectionRepositoryModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new KafkaModule());
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MotionDetection).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<MotionHub>("/motionhub");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }

    static class CustomExtensionsMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create background services to:
        /// 1: Create Kafka topic from config if not already created
        /// 2: Mqtt->Kafka Bridge for object detections
        /// 3: Consume Kafka object detections and forward to signalR
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Service collection</param>
        public static IServiceCollection AddBackgroundServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<KafkaAdminService>();
            services.AddHostedService<MqttKafkaBridge>();
            services.AddHostedService<ConsumerService>();

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (!configuration.GetSection(S3Config.SectionName).Exists())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to locate section {S3Config.SectionName} in config file");
            }
            services.Configure<S3Config>(options => configuration.GetSection(S3Config.SectionName).Bind(options));

            if (!configuration.GetSection(MqttConfig.SectionName).Exists())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to locate section {MqttConfig.SectionName} in config file");
            }
            services.Configure<MqttConfig>(options => configuration.GetSection(MqttConfig.SectionName).Bind(options));

            if (!configuration.GetSection(KafkaConfig.SectionName).Exists())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to locate section {KafkaConfig.SectionName} in config file");
            }
            services.Configure<KafkaConfig>(options => configuration.GetSection(KafkaConfig.SectionName).Bind(options));

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomSignalR(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var loggerMD = sp.GetService<ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter>>();
            var loggerMI = sp.GetService<ILogger<MotionInfoConverter>>();
            var loggerJV = sp.GetService<ILogger<JsonVisitor>>();

            services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true)
               .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
               {
                   options.PayloadSerializerOptions = JsonConvertersFactory.CreateDefaultJsonConverters(loggerMD, loggerMI, loggerJV);
               });

            return services;
        }
    }
```

**Background Service that sends Create Topic Request To Kafka - BLOCKING WHEN USING WebApplicationFactory Test Server**

```
    public delegate IAdminClient KafkaAdminFactory(KafkaConfig config);
    public class KafkaAdminService : IHostedService
    {
        private KafkaAdminFactory _Factory { get; set; }
        private ILogger<KafkaAdminService> _Logger { get; set; }
        private KafkaConfig _Config { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve KafkaConfig from appsettings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config">Config POCO from appsettings file</param>
        /// <param name="clientFactory"><see cref="KafkaAdminFactory"/></param>
        /// <param name="logger">Logger instance</param>
        public KafkaAdminService(
            IOptions<KafkaConfig> config,
            KafkaAdminFactory clientFactory,
            ILogger<KafkaAdminService> logger)
        {
            if (clientFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));

            if (config == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

            _Config = config.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
            _Factory = clientFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));
            _Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Create a Kafka topic if it does not already exist
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Cancellation token required by IHostedService</param>
        /// <exception name="CreateTopicsException">
        /// Thrown for exceptions encountered except duplicate topic
        /// </exception>
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var client = _Factory(_Config))
            {
                await CreateTopicAsync(client);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Dispatch request to Kafka Broker to create Kafka topic from config</summary>
        /// <param name="client">Kafka admin client</param>
        /// <exception cref="">Thrown for errors except topic already exists</exception>
        private async Task CreateTopicAsync(IAdminClient client)
        {
            try
            {
                _Logger.LogInformation("Admin service trying to create Kafka Topic...");
                _Logger.LogInformation($"Topic::{_Config.Topic.Name}, ReplicationCount::{_Config.Topic.ReplicationCount}, PartitionCount::{_Config.Topic.PartitionCount}");
                _Logger.LogInformation($"Bootstrap Servers::{_Config.Consumer.BootstrapServers}");

                await client.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] {
                        new TopicSpecification {
                            Name = _Config.Topic.Name,
                            NumPartitions = _Config.Topic.PartitionCount,
                            ReplicationFactor = _Config.Topic.ReplicationCount
                        }
                    }, null);

                _Logger.LogInformation($"Admin service successfully created topic {_Config.Topic.Name}");
            }
            catch (CreateTopicsException e)
            {
                if (e.Results[0].Error.Code != ErrorCode.TopicAlreadyExists)
                {
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"An error occured creating topic {_Config.Topic.Name}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
                    throw e;
                }
                else
                {
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"Topic {_Config.Topic.Name} already exists");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>No-op</summary>
        /// <param name="token">Cancellation token</param>
        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token) => await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

**GitLab pipeline running the same docker-compose stack remotely**

Creates .env file for pipeline variables and spins up docker-compose stack

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:19.03.11-dind

test:
  image: docker/compose:debian-1.27.4
  stage: test
  variables:
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
    COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD: 1
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - cd Docker
    - echo "MQTT_USER=${MQTT_USER}" >> .env
    - echo "MQTT_PASSWORD=${MQTT_PASSWORD}" >> .env
    - echo "MINIO_USER=${MINIO_USER}" >> .env
    - echo "MINIO_PASSWORD=${MINIO_PASSWORD}" >> .env
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-ci.yml build webapp
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-ci.yml up --exit-code-from webapp --abort-on-container-exit
```

**GitLab CI Job Output**

Correct test environment variables have been read and displayed via debugging on CI

```sh
netclient-run     | .NET Run Web App Ready. Starting WebApp that contains KafkaAdmin background service.
netclient-test    | Giving netclient-run a bit of time to start up…
netclient-run     | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
netclient-run     |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
netclient-run     | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
netclient-run     |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {395ba0f4-cde9-49af-8fb4-fd16b9f05bae} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
netclient-run     | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-run     |       Admin service trying to create Kafka Topic...
netclient-run     | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-run     |       Topic::eventbus, ReplicationCount::1, PartitionCount::3
netclient-run     | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-run     |       Bootstrap Servers::kafka:9092
netclient-run     | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-run     |       Admin service successfully created topic eventbus
netclient-run     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
netclient-run     |       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
netclient-run     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
netclient-run     |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
netclient-run     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
netclient-run     |       Hosting environment: Docker
netclient-run     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
netclient-run     |       Content root path: /KafkaAdmin/src/KafkaAdmin.WebApp


netclient-test    | .NET Client test container ready. Running test that uses WebApplicationFactory TestServer to start WebApp with KafkaAdmin background service
netclient-test    | This runs successfully in a local development environment on MacOS and Ubuntu Linux 16.04.
netclient-test    | This fails when running on a GitLab CI Server. It can be seen that the test server bootstraps the WebApp.....
netclient-test    | The KafkaAdmin background service blocks when requesting topic creation from the kafka service
netclient-test    | Test run for /KafkaAdmin/tests/KafkaAdmin.Kafka.IntegrationTests/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-musl-x64/KafkaAdmin.Kafka.IntegrationTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
netclient-test    | Starting test execution, please wait...
netclient-test    | 
netclient-test    | A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
netclient-test    | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
netclient-test    |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
netclient-test    | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
netclient-test    |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {2b234f03-01b4-472d-9621-db8e056db173} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
netclient-test    | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-test    |       Admin service trying to create Kafka Topic...
netclient-test    | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-test    |       Topic::eventbus, ReplicationCount::1, PartitionCount::3
netclient-test    | info: KafkaAdmin.Kafka.KafkaAdminService[0]
netclient-test    |       Bootstrap Servers::kafka:9092
```

**docker-compose**

Contains Kafka, Zookeeper and WebApp(Source+Tests) services in same network. If alter the command for the WebApp server to run the Software Under Tests WebApp then runs successfully on CI. Only experience the issue when using WebApplicationFactory Test Server on remote GitLan CI server.

```yaml
---
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - camnet
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: WARN

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - camnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: WARN
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.zookeeper=WARN,org.apache.kafka=WARN,kafka=WARN,kafka.cluster=WARN,kafka.controller=WARN,kafka.coordinator=WARN,kafka.log=WARN,kafka.server=WARN,kafka.zookeeper=WARN,state.change.logger=WARN"

  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.9
    hostname: mqtt
    container_name: mqtt
    ports:
      - "8883:8883"
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9901:9001"
    networks:
      - camnet
    environment:
      - MOSQUITTO_USERNAME=${MQTT_USER}
      - MOSQUITTO_PASSWORD=${MQTT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./Mqtt/Config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./Mqtt/Certs/localCA.crt:/mosquitto/config/ca.crt
      - ./Mqtt/Certs/server.crt:/mosquitto/config/server.crt
      - ./Mqtt/Certs/server.key:/mosquitto/config/server.key

  minio:
    image: dcs3spp/minio:version-1.0.2
    hostname: minio
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - camnet
    environment:
      - MINIO_BUCKET=images
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_USER}
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_PASSWORD}

  webapp:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Docker/Test/Dockerfile.debian
      target: test
    hostname: webapp
    container_name: webapp
    image: dcs3spp/webapp
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - minio
      - mqtt
    networks:
      - camnet
    entrypoint: []
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "
        echo Waiting for kafka service start...;
        while ! nc -z kafka 9092;
        do
          sleep 1;
        done;
        echo Connected!;
        dotnet test ./Tests/FunctionalTests/WebApp.FunctionalTests;
      "
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - MqttSettings__UserName=${MQTT_USER}
      - MqttSettings__Password=${MQTT_PASSWORD}
      - S3Settings__AccessKey=${MINIO_USER}
      - S3Settings__SecretKey=${MINIO_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ../CoverageReports:/CoverageReports

networks:
  camnet:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this *aspnetcore* [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6395) discovered that the problem was with the implementation
of my `IHostedService` implementation.

The `StartAsync` method was performing the task, running until the request completed. By design this method is meant to be fire and forget, i.e. start the task and then continue. Updated my `KafkaAdmin` service to be a `BackgroundService`, overriding `ExecuteAsync` method, as listed below.
Subsequently, tests no longer blocks.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.Kafka.Admin;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

using KafkaAdmin.Kafka.Config;


namespace KafkaAdmin.Kafka
{
    public delegate IAdminClient KafkaAdminFactory(KafkaConfig config);

    /// <summary>Background Service to make a request from Kafka to create a topic</summary>
    public class KafkaAdminService : BackgroundService, IDisposable
    {
        private KafkaAdminFactory _Factory { get; set; }
        private ILogger<KafkaAdminService> _Logger { get; set; }
        private KafkaConfig _Config { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve KafkaConfig from appsettings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config">Config POCO from appsettings file</param>
        /// <param name="clientFactory"><see cref="KafkaAdminFactory"/></param>
        /// <param name="logger">Logger instance</param>
        public KafkaAdminService(
            IOptions<KafkaConfig> config,
            KafkaAdminFactory clientFactory,
            ILogger<KafkaAdminService> logger)
        {
            if (clientFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));

            if (config == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

            _Config = config.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
            _Factory = clientFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));
            _Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Create a Kafka topic if it does not already exist
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Cancellation token required by IHostedService</param>
        /// <exception name="CreateTopicsException">
        /// Thrown for exceptions encountered except duplicate topic
        /// </exception>
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (var client = _Factory(_Config))
            {
                try
                {
                    _Logger.LogInformation("Admin service trying to create Kafka Topic...");
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"Topic::{_Config.Topic.Name}, ReplicationCount::{_Config.Topic.ReplicationCount}, PartitionCount::{_Config.Topic.PartitionCount}");
                    _Logger.LogInformation($"Bootstrap Servers::{_Config.Consumer.BootstrapServers}");

                    await client.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] {
                        new TopicSpecification {
                            Name = _Config.Topic.Name,
                            NumPartitions = _Config.Topic.PartitionCount,
                            ReplicationFactor = _Config.Topic.ReplicationCount
                        }
                    }, null);

                    _Logger.LogInformation($"Admin service successfully created topic {_Config.Topic.Name}");
                }
                catch (CreateTopicsException e)
                {
                    if (e.Results[0].Error.Code != ErrorCode.TopicAlreadyExists)
                    {
                        _Logger.LogInformation($"An error occured creating topic {_Config.Topic.Name}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
                        throw e;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _Logger.LogInformation($"Topic {_Config.Topic.Name} already exists");
                    }
                }
            }

            _Logger.LogInformation("Kafka Consumer thread started");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Call base class dispose
        /// </summary>
        public override void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Still confused as to why the live WebApp starts successfully. Why is this just an issue for the TestServer?