# ASP.NET Core - Where to perform an initialisation task before spawning background services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am learning ASP.NET Core and would like to perform a single **asynchronous** initialisation task before spawning background services. The initialisation task sets up kafka topics etc. based upon information in the appsettings.{Environment}.json config.

Is this best done in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class? (See answer)

Comment: As you suggest, I do startup desalinization (like pre-load data in cache) in `Startup.Configure`. You can inject services as parameter.

Comment: Cheers, thanks @verno, appreciated :)

Comment: Assuming would have to something like suggested in this [article](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/) or [here](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-2/#an-example-async-database-migration) for initialisation task that is async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task to setup the Kafka Topic is asynchronous and `Startup.Configure` is synchronous.

I eventually made the decision to use Thomas Levesque's [Extensions.Hosting.AsyncInitialization](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Extensions.Hosting.AsyncInitialization) to perform the Kafka topic creation.

For testing with xUnit and `WebApplicationFactory` I used a class fixture to perform the topic creation from test config before starting the `WebApplicationFactory` test server. See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64918405/12152982) with a problem that I encountered with the test server blocking.